# UITableView header view bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have next issue:

this code worked well:

//UITableViewController class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80)];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = v;
}
```

Result:
[image]
But next code is not worked:

// TopViewController class

```
@interface TopViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

// UITableViewController class

```
@property (strong) TopViewController *topBar;
@synthesize topBar;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    topBar = [[TopViewController alloc] init];
    topBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 80);
    [topBar.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = topBar.view;
}
```

Result - just white space

[image]

But when i do this:

```
topBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 400); // change height to 400
```

I've got next result:

[image]

Can some one explain this strange behavior?

Comment: You're not calling `[super viewDidLoad]` in the second example. I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem, but it would be good practice to call it just in case.

Comment: Also, is there any reason you're creating a whole view controller to manage the header view? The issue could have something to do with the view controller that owns the view resizing it at some point. In any case, you should not be using views of other view controllers in random places without view controller containment.

Comment: There is just simple view for example. I need view, which should show/hide when i tap on it, and which contain view of other view controllers. Is there any other way for do this? @PartiallyFinite

Comment: Create a simple view, and add the view of your custom view controller as a subview using view controller containment (see [this post](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html) for a better explanation of how it works) — simply `addSubview` isn't good enough.